Want to show that this sum vanishes modulo p
Let $p\ge 5$ be a prime number, and consider the following sum:
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{v_0 = 1}^{p - 2} \binom{p - 2}{v_0} \, \theta^{v_0 - 1}(Y) \cdot \theta^{p - 2 - v_0}(Y) \\
&+ \frac{1}{Y} \sum_{v_0 = 2}^{p - 2} \sum_{v_1 = 1}^{v_0 - 1} \binom{v_0 - 1}{v_1} \binom{p - 1}{v_0} \, \theta^{v_1 - 1}(Y) \cdot \theta^{v_0 - 1 - v_1}(Y) \cdot \theta^{p - 1 - v_0}(Y)
\end{align}
where $Y = \theta^{0}(Y)$ and each $\theta^{k}(Y)$ for some $k\ge0$ is considered to be just an independent variable.
How can I show that this sum vanishes completely modulo $p$. Any insight will be very much appreciated (especially a combinatorial argument).

There must be a typo. For $p=3$ the result is $Y^2$, and for $p=5$ something like $13Y_1^2+8YY_2$.

I have corrected myself. It shouldn't just be any prime. I am looking at primes greater than or equal to 5.

It does work for $p=5$, I get $5(3\theta^1(Y)+2Y\theta^2(Y))$

So $\theta^k(Y)$ should be thought of as a formal symbol $Y_k$, and we're looking to show that this vanishes as an element of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[Y_0, \dotsc, Y_{p - 3}]$?  That is, I shouldn't think of $\theta^k(Y)$ as actually functions of some $Y$?

Sorry, the correct expression for $p=5$ is $5(3\theta_1(Y)^2+2Y\theta^2(Y))$

It is easy to see that
$$
YS=\sum_{\substack{i+j+k=p-3\\i,j,k\geqslant0}}\binom{i+j+k+2}{i+j+2}\binom{i+j+1}{i+1}\theta^i(Y)\theta^j(Y)\theta^k(Y)
$$
It follows that the coefficient at $\theta^i(Y)\theta^j(Y)\theta^k(Y)$ is
$$
\sum_\sigma\frac{(p-1)!}{(\sigma(i)+\sigma(j)+2)(\sigma(i)+1)!\sigma(j)!\sigma(k)!}
$$
where the sum is over all permutations $\sigma$ of $(i,j,k)$. This sum is
\begin{multline*}
\frac{(p-1)!}{(i+1)!(j+1)!(k+1)!}\left(\frac{(j+1)(k+1)}{i+j+2}+\frac{(i+1)(k+1)}{i+j+2}\right.\\+\frac{(j+1)(k+1)}{i+k+2}+\frac{(i+1)(j+1)}{i+k+2}\\\left.+\frac{(i+1)(k+1)}{j+k+2}+\frac{(i+1)(j+1)}{j+k+2}\right)\\
=\frac{(p-1)!}{(i+1)!(j+1)!(k+1)!}(k+1+j+1+i+1)\\
=\frac{p!}{(i+1)!(j+1)!(k+1)!}
\end{multline*}
which is divisible by $p$.

What is $\sigma$?  The sum of divisors?

@LSpice $\sigma$ is any permutation of ${i,j,k}$, added it

@მამუკა ჯიბლაძე. Thank you very much for this insight. This is very helpful
